# Magento -site not opening after CLI -installation

Tags: magento2, nginx, php-fpm

I am trying to get Magento 2 installed on my Centos7 LEMP-stack, but after a successful CLI-installation and setting the Magento on Developer-mode, I get the following message when trying to open the page:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_c1qi0gaoj25njvfbt92lee4ao6, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_c1qi0gaoj25njvfbt92lee4ao6, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'SessionHandler:...', '/var/www/magent...', 22, Array)
#1 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php(22): SessionHandler->read('c1qi0gaoj25njvf...')
#2 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php(93): Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler\Native->read('c1qi0gaoj25njvf...')
#3 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler->read('c1qi0gaoj25njvf...')
#4 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(189): session_start()
#5 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start()
#6 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->___callPlugins('start', Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(130): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->start()
#8 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\State))
#9 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\State))
#10 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#11 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#12 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#13 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'session', 'Magento\\Store\\A...')
#14 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Store\\A...', Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Store\\A...')
#16 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Store\\A...')
#17 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'redirect', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#18 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)
#19 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#20 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#21 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'context', 'Magento\\Cms\\Con...')
#22 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', Array, Array)
#23 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Cms\\Con...', Array)
#24 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ActionFactory.php(40): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Cms\\Con...')
#25 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(300): Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create('Magento\\Cms\\Con...')
#26 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(161): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Array)
#27 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(50): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#30 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#31 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#34 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#37 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#40 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#43 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#45 /var/www/magento2/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#46 {main}
```

So I go see those directories, and notice that the /var/www/magento2/var/lib/php/session" -path does not exist, but there is shorter "var/www/magento2/var/session" -path existing instead, and it has "sess_" -file inside of it.

Am I supposed to change some config -file to point into that directory instead? And if I am, where and what file would that be? Or is it something else completely?

EDIT: 
My local user has been added to webservers group and permissions are set as following:

```
chown -R myuser:webservergroup /var/www/magento2/
chmod -R 755 /var/www/magento2/
chmod -R 777 /var/www/magento2/var/
chmod -R 777 /var/www/magento2/pub/
```

My PHP.ini is currently set as following (orginally save_path was commented out):

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "var/www/magento2/var/session"
```

PHP.env didn't have 'save_path' directive so I added it:

```
  'session' =>
     array (
    'save' => 'files',
    'save_path' => '/var/session',
   ),
```

But still having the same issue.

Comment: I think your problem's related to permission. Please, check the user permission again.

Comment: Also see if you're setting a session directory in `php.ini`. That overrides Magento's default of `var/session` and might cause this issue. See [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/sessions.html).

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I added some more information about my permissions and php.ini and php.env -files.

Comment: You tried the way @SteveJohnson mentioned?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I tried the following changes: In php.env, I added line 'save_path' => '/var/session', and in php.ini I uncommented the session.save_path directive and edited it to: session.save_path = "var/www/magento2/var/session". Still having the same issue.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Allright, I managed to get it work by editing 'save_path' -directive in php.env once more. I had to use complete path '/var/www/magento2/var/session', in order to get it work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So this solved this for me, thank you @Steve Johnson.

Edited php.ini file:

```
session.save_handler = files
;session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

-->

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "var/www/magento2/var/session"
```

Edited php.env file:

```
'session' =>
     array (
    'save' => 'files',
   ),
```

-->

```
'session' =>
     array (
    'save' => 'files',
    'save_path' => '/var/www/magento2/var/session',
   ),
```

Answer (score 5):

Thank you so much this also helped me fix my problem...

I had used the free Softaculous Installer via my cPanel to install Magento v2.2.6  It said the installation was successful but when trying to access Magento I got the error "There has been an error processing your request".

I found the detailed error messages in the `./var/reports` directory and they looked like this:

> Warning: SessionHandler::read():
>   open(195.201.9.76:11211/sess_0622981ed0e8a3aaf857122afbd443a7, O_RDWR)
>   failed: No such file or directory (2) in
>   //public_html//vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php
>   on line 22

So my session directory was in a slightly different place from the above solution...I added a save_path entry into my `./app/etc/env.php` file....in the session section like this:

```
'session' =>
     array (
    'save' => 'files',
    'save_path' => './vendor/magento/framework/Session'
   ),
```

And then it worked fine!

Comment: But it is not work

Comment: It worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

edit /app/etc/env.php file

```
'session' => [
    'save' => 'files',
    'save_path' => 'D:\wamp64\www\projectName\var\session' // put full directory path
],
```

it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

check app/etc/env.php

and remove line - SESSION save_path