# Magento 2.1.1 SessionHandler::read(): Write of lock failed

Tags: magento-2.1, installation

I try to install Mage 2 to my Ubuntu, Apache2, PHP7, MySql. 
First time a had error binded with not installed memcached. I have installed it. Then i have:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: SessionHandler::read(): Write of lock failed in /var/www/magento2.ubu/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22
```

May be someone has solution to this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like memcache is not properly configured. This may be permission issue. If you just want your instance to run try first changing session to files in `app/etc/env.php`

```
return array(
    ...
    'session' =>
        array(
            'save' => 'files',
        ),
    ...
);
```

Comment: I've done as you suggest, and i have: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(var/www/magento2.ubu/var/session/sess_mmo542ludc7mpbtkimtegl43g3, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /var/www/magento2.ubu/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22

Comment: I resolve it like was here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125264/magento-site-not-opening-after-cli-installation